# PDO Select with multiple WHERE and Value between number of mysql column

Tags: php, mysql

I create this table "plan"

```
======================
| id | name | status |
| 1  | Alpha|   1    |
| 2  | Beta |   1    |
| 3  | Char |   1    |
======================
```

And this table as sub of plans "plans_sub"

```
===================================
| id | name | min | max | main_id |
| 1  | v1   |  1  | 10  |    2    |
| 2  | v2   | 11  | 20  |    2    |
| 3  | v3   | 21  | 100 |    2    |
===================================
```

I created a form which is contains input type number. After submitted the form It will send a "plan_id" and "amount" data.

I want to get the database select based on the form submitted data. For example the form send me plan_id = 2 and amount = 11 then I created this PDO.

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM plans p INNER JOIN plans_sub ps ON ps.main_id = p.id WHERE ps.main_id = :pid AND (min >= :amount OR min IS NULL) AND (max <= :amountOne OR max IS NULL)");
$stmt->bindValue(':pid',$_POST['plan_id']);
$stmt->bindValue(':amount',$_POST['amount']);
$stmt->bindValue(':amountOne',$_POST['amount']);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$planId = $stmt->fetch();
```

When I try to get the result by print it.

```
print_r($planId);
```

It gave me no data. It should give me data of

```
Plan: Beta
plan sub: v2
```

because of the submited data is plan id 2 (main_id in plans_sub) and amount 11.

=========================================

## EDIT

I try to use foreach like this

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM plans p INNER JOIN plans_sub ps ON ps.main_id = p.id WHERE main_id = :pid");
$stmt->bindValue(':pid',$_POST['plan_id']);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$plans = $stmt->fetchAll();
foreach ($plans as $key => $value) {
 if($_POST['amount']>=$value['min'] && $_POST['amount']<=$value['max']){
     $planid = $value;
 }
}
```

and print_r($planid ) to see the result. Yes it give me **Beta v2** with submitted form amount = 11 and plan_id = 2.

But I have next questions. How if the submitted form is amount = 0 and plan_id = 2 ?? If the submitted form is like that I want to show the result as a **Beta v1** with amount change to 1 as the minimal min in the "plans_sub".

Can anyone help me to fetch the data?

Comment: I don't get it. If the user submits 0, why do you want 1?

Comment: Because the minimal in "plans" Beta which is "plans_sub" v1 is 1 not 0. So the script will continue but without error because she/he input 0, it will continue with the minimal 1 in its "plans_sub"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the way. 
First we search for amount if less than and then search if amount greater than. last the real searching by our logic. Here is the code.

```
            foreach ($plans as $key => $value) {
                if($_POST['amount']<$value['min']){
                    $planid = $value;
                    break;
                }elseif($_POST['amount']>$value['max']){
                    $planid = $value;
                    continue;
                }elseif($_POST['amount']>=$value['min'] && $_POST['amount']<=$value['max']){
                    $planid = $value;
                    break;
                }
            }
```

Hope can help others

Answer (score 0):

You query

```
SELECT * 
FROM plans p 
INNER JOIN plans_sub ps ON ps.main_id = p.id 
WHERE ps.main_id = :pid 
AND (min >= :amount OR min IS NULL  ) 
AND (max <= :amountOne OR max IS NULL)
```

return no value because You have not a valid value for :amountOne if you want Beta Plan you should pass  id = 2, amount = 11  na amountOne  = 18

could be you need  some code for manage empty param eg:

```
SELECT * 
FROM plans p 
INNER JOIN plans_sub ps ON ps.main_id = p.id 
WHERE ps.main_id = :pid 
AND (min >= :amount OR min IS NULL  OR IFNULL( :amount,'') =='') 
AND (max <= :amountOne OR max IS NULL OR IFNULL( :amountOne,'') =='');
```

Comment: please see my updated first page. I found the way to show what I want. But the next problem is whether the submitted form are amount = 0 and plan_id = 2. The result should be Beta v1 which is the minimal plans_sub

Comment: Then you should use min = 0 ( not 1 )  as minimal value

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you're after this...

```
SELECT * FROM plans_sub ORDER BY ABS(0-min) LIMIT 1;
+----+------+-----+-----+---------+
| id | name | min | max | main_id |
+----+------+-----+-----+---------+
|  1 | v1   |   1 |  10 |       2 |
+----+------+-----+-----+---------+
```